# Social Media Sticky Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The following code produces a nice social media sticky that aligns to the middle left of the page. It is perfect, except the social icons are horizontal and overlaps content. How can I get this so that it is vertical, on the side with the social badges in bullet format.

```
/*Make Social Media Sticky*/

#et-social-icons {
position: fixed;
z-index: 11;
left: 0;
top: 45%;
background-color: #333333;
padding: 5px 2px 2px 3px;
margin: 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

#et-social-icons a {
padding: 0;
clear: both;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more of you mark up to be sure but it seems as though you would need to remove:

display: inline-block;
float: left;

these would cause them to cascade horizontally.

Comment: It is in the custom css for WordPress. I removed those and there was no change. That was my thought too.

Comment: what about removing those and adding display: block;